Prove $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}>\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k!}$ without resorting to $\rm e$.
Clearly, it holds that $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}>{\rm e}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}>\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k!}.$$
But what if we are not allowed to using any information about ${\rm e}$.
Someone posted a proof as follows, 
Is it correct？ Is there anyother method？
